# Share different content on different apps via my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, share

I am trying to share a content on gmail and whatsapp from my iOS app. The content contains new line character. For whatsapp `<br>` is used and for gmail `\n` is used. How can I check which app user has selected whether it's whatsapp or gmail?

Comment: can you show some code what you had try out

Comment: Actually I am using branch to share. 
branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(with: linkProperties, andShareText: textToShare, from: self, completion: {activityType, completed in
            
            if(completed)
            {
                self.recordUserAction(event: event,shareType:"share")
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
            
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            
        })

Comment: But i can remove branch if I get some way of doing it natively

Comment: You can use native ios share option

Comment: But I am not able  to check which app the user has clicked to share the content.